# Can I compare a string with a list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large string of text which I wish to search for certain words. The words are stored in a list. Is it possible (and if so then how) to compare the string with the words in the list so that python **returns all the found words and their locations**, like this;

```
text = 'Theres a voice that keeps on calling me. Down the road, thats where Ill always be. Every stop I make, I make a new friend. Cant stay for long, just turn around and Im gone again. Maybe tomorrow, Ill want to settle down, Until tomorrow, I’ll just keep moving on.'

search_list = ['voice', 'Until', 'gone']

print(compare(text, search_list))

#returns something like: {voice: 11, Until: 112, gone: 54}
#p.s. the locations are random since I couldn't be bothered to count the characters
#but the format is something like {found_term: position of first character} 
#(compare doesn't necessarily have to return the results in dictionary format)
```

I have tried searching on stack overflow and google but most similar questions are about comparing 2 strings or 2 lists.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `str.index` & a loop

Comment: What if there is more than one instance of that word in the text? what should be the output for example if the word voice appeared 2 or 3 times in the text? should it output all its positions in a list? should it be the first postiion or last position?

Comment: `{word: text.find(word) for word in search_list if word in text}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.index()` on a string to get the position of a substring:

```
from typing import List, Dict


def compare(text: str, search_list: List[str]) -> Dict[str, int]:
    return {
        word: text.index(word)
        for word in search_list  
    }
```